# unique_ptr配列にオブジェクトを入れる方法

Tags: c++

C++初心者です。
とあるサイトで下のようなポリモーフィズムのサンプルコードが有りまして、
（クラスは省略しています）

```
int main() {
    Animal* theArray[5];

    theArray[0] = new Dog;
    theArray[1] = new Cat;
    theArray[2] = new Horse;
    theArray[3] = new Pig;
    theArray[4] = new Animal;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        theArray[i]->Speak();
    }
}
```

このサンプルはdeleteしていないのでメモリーリークがありまして、
コードの下に
delete theArray[0];
delete theArray[1];
delete theArray[2];
delete theArray[3];
delete theArray[4];
を追加することで収まりましたが、面倒なのでスマートポインタがいいのではないかと思いまして、
下のように書きましたが、エラーで動きません。

```
int main() {
    unique_ptr<Animal[]> theArray = make_unique<Animal[]>(5);

    theArray[0] = make_unique<Dog>();
    theArray[1] = make_unique<Cat>();
    theArray[2] = make_unique<Horse>();
    theArray[3] = make_unique<Pig>();
    theArray[4] = make_unique<Animal>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        theArray[i]->Speak();
    }
}
```

unique_ptr配列にオブジェクトを入れる方法をはありますでしょうか？

ちなみに、vectorだったら下のようにしてうまくいきました。

```
int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<Animal>> theArray;

    theArray.emplace_back(make_unique<Dog>());
    theArray.emplace_back(make_unique<Cat>());
    theArray.emplace_back(make_unique<Horse>());
    theArray.emplace_back(make_unique<Pig>());
    theArray.emplace_back(make_unique<Animal>());

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        theArray[i]->Speak();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`theArray`は、要素が`unique_ptr`で、それ自身も動的に確保しているので`unique_ptr`ということで、

```
unique_ptr<unique_ptr<Animal>[]> theArray = make_unique<unique_ptr<Animal>[]>(5);
```

と定義する必要があります。`unique_ptr<Animal>[]`は、要素の型が `unique_ptr<Animal>`である配列を表しています。それで`unique_ptr<unique_ptr<Animal>[]>`は、全体として`unique_ptr<Animal>`を要素に持つ配列を指す`unique_ptr`ということになります。

これでも問題はないと思いますが、私だったら、配列のサイズが実行時にならないと分からないときは、例に挙げられているように`std::vector`を、コンパイル時にサイズが分かっているなら`std::array`か普通の配列を使います。個人的には、`std::vector`と同じように使える`std::array`の方が、普通の配列より好みです。

#### std::array の場合

```
#include <array>
// 省略

int main() {
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Animal>, 5> theArray;

    theArray[0] = std::make_unique<Dog>();
    // 省略
```

#### 普通の配列の場合

```
// 省略

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> theArray[5];

    theArray[0] = std::make_unique<Dog>();
    // 省略
```

Comment: 普通の配列の場合の例でよくわかりました。
ありがとうございます。